# How do I make this quick-bread recipe less moist?

Tags: baking, quickbread, moisture

I modified a Paleo quick bread recipe so I could make it without any flour - coconut, nut, or other alternative. It is really good but super moist. Grilling it helps, but is there something I'm missing in the recipe? I haven't yet tried to pat dry the shredded carrots. Thoughts?

Coconut Carrot Quick Bread

- 2/3 cup processed dried flake coconut
- 1 tsp. cinnamon
- dash sea salt
- 1/2 tsp baking soda
- 5 eggs
- 1 tsp. vanilla extract
- 2.5 cups shredded carrots (medium grate)

Combine coconut, cinnamon, sea salt, baking soda. In separate bowl, beat eggs and vanilla. Add dry to wet, mix thoroughly, add grated carrot. Pour into glass bread loaf dish greased with coconut oil. Bake at 325 degrees F. for 1.25 hours or until done. Best served grilled in frying pan, warm. (recipe by ZeraMarie)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what done is for this; maybe you just need to bake it longer? That should drive out water—though possibly it will cause other problems. But probably it'll be OK since you can grill it.

I think getting some water out of the shredded carrots is the first thing to try—they have a lot of water (like all vegetables). Patting them dry will remove some. Pressing them between dry towels/paper towels will remove more. Roasting (or sautéing) them can remove even more (and will change the flavor). Or you could use a food dehydrator or low oven to just dry them.

Reducing the amount of carrot may help too, but that will again alter the flavor.

Another thing that might help: I suspect you have the eggs for binding & richness. That's mostly the yolk—you could try leaving out some or all of the whites (using the yolk only).

Comment: Or even a combination of yolks and whole eggs... like two or three whole eggs plus three or two yolks or something similar. No need to cut out all of the whites.

Comment: @Catija good point, suggestion incorporated.

Comment: You could probably also salt the carrots and let them sit a bit before squeezing. Works for things like zucchini bread, at least.

Comment: Thank you for the great tips!! Greatly appreciated. I'll give them a try.